# Moving pre-installed apps to SD-card (ROOTED)

Tags: internal-storage, 5.1-lollipop, link2sd, motorola-moto-e

i'm running a Moto E with android version 5.1 Lollipop, and since updating to this version of android I have had constantly so little space on the internal memory that I can't even update the pre-installed apps even though I have as good as as no other apps installed on the phone as well as zero images, videos, music or any other media files.

Therefore I've spent a few days trying to figure out how I could move the pre-installed apps to my SD-card.
So, I've rooted the phone, installed the program called Link2SD and I tried using that program to move the apps. Yet it gave me a warning:

"Failure
pkg: /data/app/com.google.android.apps.maps-1/base.apk Failure
[INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_INSTALL_LOCATION]"

Then I found that it seems I also need to create a so-called "second partition" on my SD-card, but I've not yet managed to find a tutorial on the internet that worked for me.

Since then I've tried 6 or 7 other similar programs with no luck, in the process reading somewhere that it actually couldn't even be done on android versions 4.0 or later. Is this true? Could someone be a kind gentleman (or -woman) and guide me through this? That would make me very happy indeed.

**EDIT:**

**In short, my two essential questions seem to be:**

**1. Is it possible to move pre-installed apps (Google apps mostly) to an SD-card on Moto E with 5.1 Lollipop.**

**2. And if so, how do I create a second partition on my SD-card for this purpose on Moto E with 5.1 Lollipop.**

Thanks in advance

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since you didn't deleted apps it means that they are on system partition. You can move it to SD card but longer way around. First you need root. Then (I don't know if other app can do this) install titanium backup (note you'll need pro version), than find that app in titanium backup on backup/restore list and in special features find option "convert to user app". After that you'll be able to uninstall app without any other software or move it to your sd card with link2sd or any other app you use for that.
About creating partition on your sd card, I didn't exactly done that but I'll post link here on how to..

Comment: I found a free program called "/system/app mover" instead that should be able to convert system apps to user apps too, according to [this website](http://www.droidiser.com/2012/11/how-to-convert-user-apps-to-system-apps.html).

Comment: When trying to convert a system app, it says: "Moving system apps is NOT recommended and will most definitely damage something on your system when doing so. On Android 5.0+, this feature is highly experimental and most system apps won't ever work again once moved!" Again something implies that moving system apps to SD-card is actually not do-able on my version of android.
I might try to convert an app that I'm never gonna use anyway and see what happens.

Comment: @wormple12 did you get that in titanium backup or that app you find? Try any of apps that isn't essential for Android you can try moving Google maps, drive, gmail, YouTube but don't move play store or play services. Also don't move apps which purpose you don't know.

Comment: Hi again.
Now, it seems, I have successfully used /System/App Mover to convert a lot of apps to user apps and then moved those apps to the SD-card with Link2SD.
Several issues appeared.
First a problem appeared where the phone started optimizing all apps on every single reboot, a process that takes 10-15 minutes to complete. I found a way to fix this with an app called Optimizing App Fixer.

Comment: Secondly there’s an even worse issue causing a lot of apps (it might be every single app that has been moved to the SD-card) to simply vanish in thin air! It is possible to go to Google Play and download the missing apps again. I can reboot and reboot and clear cache and reboot all I like and the issue perseveres. Then suddenly, on a reboot later the same day, all the missing apps return like they were never gone. Rebooting the phone again after this, once again makes the apps disappear without a trace.

Comment: So, it seems that the apps still exists on the SD-card, yet the phone has problems noticing those apps? Any ideas?

Comment: @wormple12 hmm, maybe the apps aren't designed to be moved to SD card this is just a guess. I had one app that was vanishing from adopted sd card I didn't know why but just that app was troublesome. Sorry I don't know how to help with that.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway. I will look into the matter and if I wind up finding nothing useful on the subject, then I'll start a new topic, because this isn't exactly the same issue/question anymore.

Comment: If files of app are gone (but that is not the case as you said that they exist but phone didn't see them) then maybe sd card is dying, and have bad sectors.